# Filter Excel Dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I am doing some merged using Pandas using a name-map because the two files I want don't have exact name names to merge on easily. But My Pdata sheet has lists of dates from 2014 to 2016, but I want to filter the sheet down to only contain dates from 1/1/2015 - 31/12/2016.
Below is the code that I currently have and I am not sure how to/if I can filter on date before the merge.

```
import pandas as pd
path=  'C:/Users/Rukgo/Desktop/Match thing/'
name_map = pd.read_excel(path+'name_map.xls',sheetname=0)
Tdata = pd.read_excel(path+'2015_TXNs.xls',sheetname=0)
pdata = pd.read_excel(path+'Pipeline.xls', sheetname=0)
#pdata = pdata[(1/1/2015 <=pdata.date)&(pdata.date <=31/12/2015)]
merged = pd.merge(Tdata, name_map, how="left", on="Local Customer")
merged.to_excel(path+"results.xls")
mdata = pd.read_excel(path +'results.xls',sheetname=0)
final_merge = pd.merge(mdata, pdata, how='right', on='Client')
final_merge = final_merge[final_merge.Amount_USD !=0]
final_merge.to_excel(path+"Final Results.xls")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a commented out section that ended up being quite close to the actual code that I needed.

```
pdata = pdata[(pdata['date']>='20150101')&(pdata['date']<='20151231')]
```

That ended up working perfectly, though hard codes the dates